# Lambda expression parse error on ")"

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

My task is to re-implement this function

```
divn :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
divn _ [] = []
divn n (x:xs) | mod x n == 0 = x : divn n xs
              | otherwise = divn n xs
```

using 'foldr'.
What I did:

```
divn' _ [] = []
divn' n (x:xs) = foldr (\x -> if (mod x n == 0) (x:) ([]++)) [] xs
```

I thought this would work. Actually it doesn't even compile, but says: "Parse error on input ")".

As I didn't find any errors, I decided to re-write if as if' an now its working...

```
if' True x _ = x
if' False _ x = x

divn' _ [] = []
divn' n (x:xs) = foldr (\x -> if' (mod x n == 0) (x:) ([]++)) [] xs
```

Does anyone know where's the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` needs a `then` and an `else` in Haskell,

```
(\x -> if (mod x n == 0) (x:) ([]++))
```

should be

```
(\x -> if (mod x n == 0) then (x:) else id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what Daniel Fischer said, you don't need any separate cases: there's no recursion, the empty list case will be handled by foldr. In your code, the first `x` is *always* ignored! Correct is

```
divn' n xs = foldr (\x -> if x`mod`n == 0 then (x:) else id) [] xs
```

or, by η-reduction,

```
divn' n = foldr (\x -> if x`mod`n == 0 then (x:) else id) []
```

Of course, it would be far more idiomatic to simply do

```
divn'' n = filter ((==0) . (`mod`n))
```

Comment: That's right, he matches on `(x:xs)` but never uses the `x`, only another variable that has incidentally (or should I say, accidentally) the same name: the parameter of the λ-function, which shadows the original `x`, effectively throwing it away.